# How do I stop people manipulating URLs to submit forms in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, url, submit

When a user submits any form, a `$_GET['variable_name']` is sent by the webpage and will give a URL like the following:  `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?variable_name_here='yes'`.

However people can just write the URL `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?variable_name='yes'` into the address bar of the website and gain access to this part of the script, without actually submitting the form!

This is a problem! It's breaking specific parts of the script linked to that form submission! This is because the part of the script relating to the `$_GET['variable_name']` can't get the variables that should be sent by the form as it is never submitted!

How do I stop people getting to specific parts of a script when they manipulate the URL by sending them back to `www.mywebsite.com/index.php`?

P.S. : This is for user submitted data through a form which is then processed (no SQL or any alike software involved)

Comment: Wait... You asked and answered the question? Or is your answer suppose to be a possible method?

Comment: Why are you not using a "POST" method instead?

Comment: So you managed to answer your own question within seconds of posting it. Do you just like to hear yourself type?

Comment: When asking questions, it gives you the option to answer your own question to share knowledge - if people don't like the solution I give then fair enough - I put it here to attempt to help someone else who may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worrying about people getting in to your site without logging in or not having correct params, you should first check to see if the correct $_GET variables exist using `isset()`. If all paramaters you are expecting exist allow them to pass, otherwise use `header('Location: /index.php');` to force a redirect.

Answer (score -2):

To redirect from `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?variable_name='yes'` to `www.mywebsite.com/index.php` you would need to include the following code below **before you open a HTML header!** This solution will work for any $_GET variables within your whole website if you place it within an `includes("filename_here")`, no need to change the code.

```
//if there are any $_GET variable(s) set (doesn't matter what the name of the variables are)
if (! empty($_GET))
{
    //if there is no record of the previous page viewed on the server
    if(! isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    {
        //get requested URL by the user
        $redir = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

        //split parts of the URL by the ?
        $redir = explode('?', $redir);

        //redirect to the URL before the first ? (this removes all $_GET variables)
        header("Location: $redir[0]");
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a need to change the code. you need to secure against SQL injection if using a database.  and if reading values back from the database and putting them on the page, you need to secure against HTML/script injection.

Comment: You could just ignore the extra input or use the isset function

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is unreliable